# replace this.function.bind(this) for function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-functional-component

I have a class component that looks like this:

```
interface MyProps {
  addingCoord: any
  resetCoords: any
}

interface MyState {
  x: any
  y: any
}

class DrawerOld extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
  width: number
  height: number

  constructor(props: MyProps) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {x: NaN, y: NaN, hoverMode: false}
    this.width = this.height = 400
  }

  onMouseMove(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) {
    this.setState(
      {
        x: parseFloat((e.nativeEvent.offsetX / this.width).toFixed(3)),
        y: parseFloat(
          ((this.height - e.nativeEvent.offsetY) / this.height).toFixed(3),
        ),
      },
      () => {
        if (this.state.hoverMode) this.addCoord()
      },
    )
  }

  toggleHoverMode() {
    this.setState({hoverMode: !this.state.hoverMode})
  }

  addingCoord() {
    const coord = {x: this.state.x, y: this.state.y}
    this.props.addingCoord(coord)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div
            onMouseMove={(e) => this.onMouseMove(e)}
            onClick={this.addCoording.bind(this)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default DrawerOld
```

I want to modify it into a functional component. However, I am unable to figure out how to accurately modify this part:
`onClick={this.addCoord.bind(this)}`

because currently if I use `onClick={props.addCoord()}`, I would get errors like these upon using it:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

```
<DrawerNew addCoord={this.addCoord.bind(this)}
                            resetCoords={this.resetCoords.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: Hi!  *"I prepared a codesandbox"* Please don't use off-site resources for runnable examples, use the **on-site**  using Stack Snippets instead (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). Four reasons: There's no chance you'll leave out something important; people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future.

Comment: Only one tiny little problem ... just omit the () after addCoord

Comment: That's pretty weird code, passing `onMouseMove` with an arrow function and then using `.bind()` for exactly the same purpose in the following line to pass `onClick`…

Comment: The functionality is different for both, might not be obvious here :) @Bergi

Comment: @Jbd No, it's not, they behave pretty much the same. You could've written `onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove.bind(this)}` and `onClick={(e) => this.addCoord(e)}`, and it would do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `onClick`

from this

```
onClick={props.addCoord()}
```

to this

```
onClick={addCoord}
```

Comment: There's no reason whatsoever to create an extra function here. Just `onClick={addCoord}`.

Comment: addCoord or props.Coord? props.Coord is the function passed as a parameter, right?